# OR condition with calculated date don't work

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to build a moving average and so I'm trying this (Yes, I'm aware of "rows between 6 preceding and current row" but's not the issue).

The code works with OR business_date = '2019-08-27', but NOT as it is below.

```
with x AS(
select
business_date
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AS r1
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 48 HOUR) AS r2
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 72 HOUR) AS r3
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 96 HOUR) AS r4
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 120 HOUR) AS r5
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 144 HOUR) AS r6
FROM `sometable`
)
select 
business_date
from x
WHERE business_date = '2019-08-28' OR business_date = r1
group by business_date
```

Comment: what is the issue in your query...post your result getting from this query and expected result with some sample data will be very helpful

Comment: I expect two rows - 2019-08-28 and 2019-08-27 but it only returns 2019-08-28

Comment: you made one row with `r1, r2, r3...` columns, how this will be give you 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

By the input and inner query you provided it will return 2 rows by using `UNION`.
Since inner query of `cte` is creating `6 columns` for each row. Remember create 6 columns so you'll get columns instead of row.

```
with x AS(
select
business_date
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AS r1
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 48 HOUR) AS r2
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 72 HOUR) AS r3
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 96 HOUR) AS r4
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 120 HOUR) AS r5
,TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 144 HOUR) AS r6
FROM `sometable`
)
select business_date from x
WHERE business_date = '2019-08-28' or  business_date = r1
group by business_date 
union  
select r1 from x
WHERE business_date = r1 or  business_date = '2019-08-28'
group by business_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to conditionally unpivot the dates.  The logic seems to be something like this:

```
SELECT r_date
FROM (SELECT timestamp('2019-08-28') as business_date) t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(ARRAY[business_date,
                  TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 24 HOUR),
                  TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 48 HOUR),
                  TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 72 HOUR),
                  TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 96 HOUR),
                  TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 120 HOUR),
                  TIMESTAMP_SUB(business_date, INTERVAL 144 HOUR) 
                 ]
           ) r_date WITH OFFSET n
WHERE n IN (0, 1);
```